# Override CakeEmail destination globally

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there an easy way to "override" the destination of an email using CakeEmail?

I have a model method that send an email using this piece of code:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->config('default');
$sent = $Email->template('new-notification')
              ->subject('A new notification for you')
              ->viewVars([
                    'name' => $foo['User']['name'],
                    'text' => $foo['Notification']['text'],
              )
              ->emailFormat('html')
              ->to($foo['User']['email'])
              ->send();
```

And this configuration:

```
class EmailConfig
{
    public $default = array(
        'host' => 'smtp.server.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'username' => 'user@domain.com',
        'password' => 'pwdAsYouKnow',
        'from' => array('noreply@domain.com' => 'Company'),
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
```

As you can see, I send the email for a dynamically defined user's email.

My objective is when I'm developing locally on my machine, to force every call to `->send()` to force a destination like `developer@domain.com`.

I can easily detect if I'm on development, but I don't know how to force in a "master" way to CakeEmail only send to a defined account overriding the one set on the call.

I already tried to set an

```
'to' => array('developer@domain.com' => 'Dev'),
```

inside `$default` but, no success.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming when you are on local machine you run in debug mode, so you can check if debug mode is on then use that to send to different email

```
if(Configure::read('debug')){
  $emailTo = 'developer@domain.com'
}
else{
  $emailTo = $foo['User']['email'];
}
```

then you just use variable for email address:

```
$sent = $Email->template('new-notification')
          ->subject('A new notification for you')
          ->viewVars([
                'name' => $foo['User']['name'],
                'text' => $foo['Notification']['text'],
          )
          ->emailFormat('html')
          ->to($emailTo)
          ->send();
```

Comment: But this would force me to put this if-block on every place that I call `->to()` isn't it? I'm looking if there's a broader option, configuration like. 

Maybe only if I encapsulate the CakeEmail class... :-/

Comment: you could add $to variable in AppController or make helper for sending email, i'm not sure about config I didn't use CakePHP that much.